# subprocess.call output in color

Tags: python, subprocess, colorama

Is there a way to display subprocess.call output in a different color and than come back to the default one? I am using colorama. but the below won't work for me. the print one works fine and prints test in green.

```
subprocess.call(["%s; " % Fore.GREEN, "hostname;" "%s" % Fore.RESET], shell=True)
subprocess.call([Fore.RED,'hostname'], shell=True)
print (Fore.GREEN,'test')
```

I have tried the above but it didn't work,

thanks for your help

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please [edit] to clarify. Also what platform are you using?

Comment: (Why would you expect putting a color code in as a command to work ever/anywhere?)

Comment: Note that when you pass an array with `shell=True`, *only the first item in that array* is parsed by the shell as code; subsequent array items are arguments to that code, starting as `$0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.call`.

subproces.run has a capture_output keyword that can be used to achieve your goal, example:

```
>>> import colorama
>>> import subprocess
>>> colorama.init(autoreset=True)
>>> out =subprocess.run(['hostname'], capture_output=True)
>>> print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + out.stdout.decode())
darknet
```

In this case, `darknet` is the hostname and it'll presumably be printed in green. I have also set the `autoreset=True`.

**Update**

```
$ docker container run --rm -it python:3.6-alpine sh
/ # pip install colorama
Collecting colorama
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/a6/728666f39bfff1719fc94c481890b2106837da9318031f71a8424b662e12/colorama-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: colorama
Successfully installed colorama-0.4.1
/ # python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Aug 21 2019, 00:27:28) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import colorama
>>> import subprocess
>>> colorama.init(autoreset=True)
>>> out = subprocess.run(['hostname'], capture_output=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'
>>> process = subprocess.run(['hostname'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(colorama.Fore.RED + process.stdout.decode())
49e3284539b8
```

From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run, the same behavior of `capture_output` can be achieved using  `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as shown above.

Comment: thanks but this did not work for me, getting TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'  ,i am using python3.6, is there any other way to achieve the result?

Comment: @greenszpila I've updated it for making it compatible with python 3.6, please check it out.